# Get marker's position by marker's name

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I get `var ble = new google.maps.Marker` position ? I've tried `ble.getPosition().lat();` but it's not working I guess I'm not naming marker and calling it right.

```
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.580622, 23.104248),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID 
    });


var london = new google.maps.LatLng(56, 22);
    var MyApp = {};

function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {
  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
        window.blia = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: london,
        draggable:true,
        map: map,
      });
  });
}

var aa = blia.getPosition();

  var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(homeControlDiv);

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: 'peace.png'
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          MyApp.xxx = this.position;
          alert(aa);
          infowindow.setContent('x' + name[i][3] + '' + name[i][4] + 'x');
          infowindow.open(map, marker);

        var request = {
         origin: MyApp.xxx, 
         destination: MyApp.posit,
         travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
     };

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }
       })

        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

Comment: ble is a local variable, so you can't reference it out side of the anonymous function where you create the marker.

Comment: Alright, but is my method of calling marker object is "good"?
How then I can get it anyways ? I tried this:
setting global var
`var MyApp = {};`
`MyApp.ble = new google.maps.Marker`

`var aa = MyApp.ble.getPosition().lat();`

Comment: Yes, assuming that the variable `london` contains a `LatLang`, and `map` contains a reference to a google map.

Comment: If it isn't working, could you post all of your code?

Comment: I tried creating same object out of function, so it's working now, but I still don't understand how to get variable, which is inside function.

Comment: If you update your code, I/we can provide you with a better answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29127/discussion-between-miah-and-user1876234)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we make some changes to the HomeControl function, it should work:

```
function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) { 
  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px'; 
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div'); 
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI); 

  var controlText = document.createElement('div'); 
  controlText.innerHTML = '<strong>Trigger</strong>'; 
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);  

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() { 
    MyApp.defaultmarker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
      position: map.getCenter(), 
      draggable:true, 
      map: map 
    }); 
  });
}
```

- all of the html elements need to be append to the element passed in controlDiv
- the variable london isn't set inside the function, so we should probably just put the marker at the center of the map.
- add the new marker to the global MyApp so that it is available after the button is control is clicked.

Remove this line, `var aa = blia.getPosition();` because blia isn't set (in the case of the new code it is MyApp.defaultmarker) until after the control is clicked, and you should be fine.